# StringBuffer и строки

Tags: java

Как мне разделить слова, тоесть работать с каждым словом?Как -то добавить их в массив, изменить,а потом вставить назад и вывести содержимое строки? Задание таково: "в каждом слове текста удалить последующие вхождения первой буквы этого слова".

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("Slava ochen krasivyi malchik");
```

Comment: Задача использовать именно StringBuffer?

Comment: вообще, да, но хотелось бы также увидеть альтернативы

Comment: Видимо задачка учебная. На первые 2 вопроса вам поможет метод String.split. Дальше пишите логику обработки слов и собираете обратно

Comment: StringBuffer устарел в 2004-м. Используйте лучше StringBuilder. Что касается самой задачи, в приведённом примере каждое слово содержит только один экземпляр буквы, с которой начинается.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Из [доков](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) восьмой версии: *Instances of StringBuilder are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that StringBuffer be used*.

Comment: @StasDorozhko перед вами пример ошибки в документации. Гетц в "Java Concurrency In Practice", Блох в "Effective Java", Флэнаган в "Java in a Nutshell" пишут о том, что `StringBuffer` не только устарел, но и абсолютно неприменим в многопоточной среде, а в однопоточной синхронизированность делает его медленным.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо за подсказку :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
String line = "Slava ochen krasivyi malchik";
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for (String word : line.split(" ")){
    stringBuffer.append(word.replace(word.substring(0, 1), ""));
    stringBuffer.append(" ");
}
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
```

lava chen rasivyi alchik